# Console error for not passing in all function arguments

Tags: javascript

Have a simple function here that I'm passing 3 arguments into, sometimes 2. When I pass in 2 the console throws the error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined

I understand that undefined is being passed in when I don't specify something to pass in to the third argument, but why would it be throwing an error in console since using arguments in JS are optional? I'd like to clear the error so end users don't see it when they open the console.

```
  toggleDisplay = (class1, class2, class3) => {
    class1.addEventListener('click', () => {
      class2.classList.toggle('displayToggle')
      class3.classList.toggle('displayToggle')
    })
  }
```

Comment: so build a check that sees if the number 3 is passed

Comment: You can pass undefined parameters just fine but you then use that parameter and that's the issue. You can't use something that is undefined.

Comment: *"since using arguments in JS are optional"* - You've specifically written a function in which the arguments are **not** optional; that is, your function is entirely dependent on all three arguments being defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to pass all the parameters, but in your case, you're *using* all the parameters. You have `class3.classList.toggle`; if you pass only two parameters, then class3 is undefined, and so trying to access its classList fails. If you want class3 to be optional, you need to check if it's not undefined before you try to actually use it.

Comment: Ahh. I was trying to avoid that, since I thought there might be a different way. I don't mind writing some logic for it if it's the only way.

Comment: Yep. JavaScript has no way of knowing what code shouldn't be run unless you tell it with conditions :) That's pretty standard in all programming languages; the code isn't psychic enough to know whether you meant to have code ignored or if you wanted it to run but messed up somewhere.

Comment: Yea. After reading your answer and checking the code again I understood what happened. Thanks for the fast response.

Answer (score 1):

```
toggleDisplay = (class1, class2, class3) => {
    class1.addEventListener('click', () => {
      class2.classList.toggle('displayToggle')
      if(class3 !== undefined ){class3.classList.toggle('displayToggle')}
    })
  }
```

Build a simple check that sees if class3 is present.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check if the third parameter is set via

```
if(class3) {
...
}
```

When paramter 3 (`class3`) is not being passed, it is `undefined`. So it has no property `classlist`. Then it will throw an error in the console.

Check this code:

```
toggleDisplay = (class1, class2, class3) => {
    class1.addEventListener('click', () => {
      class2.classList.toggle('displayToggle');
      if(class3) {
         class3.classList.toggle('displayToggle');
      }
   })
 }
```

Comment: Yep. This is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

You could do either of them, depends on your use-case

1. Do a check. Using `&&` operator you could check if given argument if has value, then proceed further. `class2 && class2.classList.toggle()`. Also if you want to give fallback method to it you could use it doing ternary operator `?` .  `class2 ? class2.classList.toggle() : otherMethod()`
2. Pass optional value, i.e. defining initial value to argument. This is used when you know object and object's property. It could be anything a string or a number.
   `toggleDisplay = (class1, class2 = {classList:{toggle:()=>{}}}, class3 = {classList:{toggle:()=>{}}}`

Comment: I'd like to point out that defaulting class3 to {} will still break here, as `{}.classList.toggle` is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

```
toggleDisplay = (class1, class2, class3) => {
   if(class1) {
     class1.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if(class2) {
            class2.classList.toggle('displayToggle')
        }
        if(class3) {
            class3.classList.toggle('displayToggle')
        }
    })
   }
  }
```

you can check parameters if available than process on it